# Are powers cumulative in Smallworld?

Tags: small-world

when playing Smallworld, we were wondering how to handle some cumulative effects. It says in the rules that all effects are cumulative unless otherwise stated. Still, we had mounted Tritons and we were wondering if they get really a +2 bonus on all hills and farmland next to the lake or coast (+1 because triton get that for any region next to water, and +1 for being mounted on hills and farmland)?

Answer (score 13):

The rule you reference is correct: powers are cumulative so you can get a +2 bonus like that. Some race/power combinations are indeed much more powerful than others in Small World; a key balancing feature is that powerful options will usually be claimed higher up the list, which means you have to pay several points to claim them, while weaker options will sit around at the bottom collecting those points until they're not looking so bad anymore. Also, remember that you *always* need at least one token to conquer a region, so a +2 bonus does not help any more than a +1 if the region is empty.

Comment: If you want further confirmation, here's a [similar BGG thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1673277/mounted-giants-question).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is useful. It does not necessarily make sense from a logical point of view as you can only either ride or swim, but you could argue with split armies etc, so fair enough. Cheers.

Comment: Powerful options are usually also balanced by having fewer tokens.

Comment: I'd say the primary balance comes from the freedom of choosing how to mess with other players. The other players should focus on harming the player in the strongest position. This is why the game doesn't work well with two players.

Comment: @GiantAlchemist If you found the answer useful, I'd appreciate it if you'd click the Accept Answer checkmark - helps me reap the rewards :)